# apparent transaction isolation violation in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, transactions

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3.12 on CentOS Linux.

I have two processes connecting to the same database, using a default transaction isolation level of "read committed". According to the postgres docs, one process in a transaction should not "see" changes made by another process in a transaction until they are committed.

A sequence I am seeing is:

- process A starts its transaction
- process A deletes everything from table T
- process B starts its transaction
- process B attempts a select for update on one row in table T
- process B comes up empty (0 rows) and calls rollback
- process A repopulates table T from incoming data
- process A commits its transaction

Now, table T should have been populated before both transactions began, and process B's query should have turned up one row. And it does if these processes do not run concurrently.

My understanding is that process B should see the old copy of the desired row in table T, makes its changes, and those changes should be clobbered by process A's deletion and repopulation of table T. I can't figure out why process B is coming up empty.

Beyond a complete misunderstanding by myself of these preconditions, can anyone think of another reason why I would see this behaviour?

Worry not about the lousy architecture, it is going away. I'm just trying to understand why this situation seems to violate the "read committed" transaction isolation as I understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you possible using "TRUNCATE TABLE" to delete everything. I think that is not transactional. According to the manual: "TRUNCATE is not MVCC-safe. "

Comment: No, it's a DELETE FROM.

Comment: What tools are you using, are you sure, that your processes work as interleaved as you expect? Are you using "BEGIN TRANSACTION"? In my opinion B really should not see the deletes before A has COMMITTED and my experiences with postgres did never show otherwise.

Comment: Sounds as if process A is actually in auto-commit mode

Comment: What you're seeing might be related to MVCC--"each SQL statement sees a snapshot of data (a database version) as it was some time ago, regardless of the current state of the underlying data." The row that B selects for update doesn't exist after A commits. Instead, there's a *new row* that happens to have some (or all) the same values.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the postgres docs, one process in a transaction should
>   not "see" changes made by another process in a transaction until they
>   are committed.

---

Yes and No - as usual, it depends. [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html) strictly says that:

> **Read Committed is the default isolation level in PostgreSQL.**
>
> When a transaction uses this isolation level, a SELECT query (**without
>   a FOR UPDATE/SHARE clause**) sees only data committed before the query
>   began; it never sees either uncommitted data or changes committed
>   during query execution by concurrent transactions. In effect, a SELECT
>   query sees a snapshot of the database as of the instant the query
>   begins to run. However, SELECT does see the effects of previous
>   updates executed within its own transaction, even though they are not
>   yet committed. Also note that two successive SELECT commands can see
>   different data, even though they are within a single transaction, if
>   other transactions commit changes after the first SELECT starts and
>   before the second SELECT starts.
>
> UPDATE, DELETE, **SELECT FOR UPDATE**, and SELECT FOR SHARE commands
>   behave the same as SELECT in terms of searching for target rows: they
>   will only find target rows that were committed as of the command start
>   time. However, such a target row might have already been updated (or
>   deleted or locked) by another concurrent transaction by the time it is
>   found. **In this case, the would-be updater will wait for the first
>   updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is still in
>   progress). If the first updater rolls back, then its effects are
>   negated and the second updater can proceed with updating the
>   originally found row. If the first updater commits, the second updater
>   will ignore the row if the first updater deleted it**, otherwise it will
>   attempt to apply its operation to the updated version of the row. The
>   search condition of the command (the WHERE clause) is re-evaluated to
>   see if the updated version of the row still matches the search
>   condition. If so, the second updater proceeds with its operation using
>   the updated version of the row. In the case of SELECT FOR UPDATE and
>   SELECT FOR SHARE, this means it is the updated version of the row that
>   is locked and returned to the client.

In other word, simply SELECT differs from SELECT FOR UPDATE/DELETE/UPDATE.
You can create simple test case to observe that behaviour:

**Session 1**

```
test=> START TRANSACTION;
START TRANSACTION
test=> SELECT * FROM test;
 x
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
(10 rows)


test=> DELETE FROM test;
DELETE 10
test=>
```

---

**Now login in another Session 2:**

```
test=> START TRANSACTION;
START TRANSACTION
test=> SELECT * FROM test;
 x
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
(10 rows)


test=> SELECT * FROM test WHERE x = 5 FOR UPDATE;
```

After the last command `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` session 1 "hangs" and is waiting for something ......

---

**Back in session 1**

```
test=> insert into test select * from generate_series(1,10);
INSERT 0 10
test=> commit;
COMMIT
```

---

**And now when you go back to session 2 you will see this:**

```
test=> SELECT * FROM test WHERE x = 5 FOR UPDATE;
 x
---
(0 rows)


test=> select * from test;
 x
----
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
 10
(10 rows)
```

---

That is - simple `SELECT` still doesn't see any changes, while  `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` does see that rows have been deleted. But it doesn't see new rows inserted by session 1

In fact a sequence you are seeing is:

- process A starts its transaction
- process A deletes everything from table T
- process B starts its transaction
- process B attempts a select for update on one row in table T
- **process B "hangs" and is waiting until session A does a commit or rollback**
- process A repopulates table T from incoming data
- process A commits its transaction
- **process B comes up empty (0 rows- after session A commit) and calls rollback**

Comment: Repeat your test, but replace your select statements with `select *, xmin, xmax from test;`. The tuple headers contain `xmin` and `xmax`; they're not reported in most metadata, but you can see them just by including their names in the `select...` statement. "B" sees different values for `xmin` and `xmax`.