# Two concurrent transactions on SERIALIZABLE isolation level

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

Let's consider two concurrent SQL transactions:

```
X = 0 
T1:                    |  T2: 
begin                  | begin
set serializable level | set serializable level
                       |  
WRITE(X,1)
                       | READ(X) : 0
COMMIT                 |  
                       | COMMIT
```

I've tested it with PosgreSQL. 
Why does `T2` commit correctly? Both transactions has serializable level. So, on my eye, **after** `T2` was started row `X` was modified. So, `T2:COMMIT` should fail. Why it does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In effect, a SELECT query sees a snapshot of the database as of the
>   instant the query begins to run. [Source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html)

A SELECT query will just operate on that snapshot. But other kinds of queries behave like you expect.

> UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, and SELECT FOR SHARE . . . will wait for the first updating transaction to commit or roll back (if it is still in progress). [Source (ibid)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/transaction-iso.html)

You can verify this behavior by, for example, running two psql sessions. Run an UPDATE statement in one session, and a SELECT...FOR UPDATE in the other.

---

The documentation quoted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45923021/562459) might confuse you a little; the documentation is about a slightly different problem. But you might find the transcript of the terminal sessions useful.